# How to convert XSD to Ecore (EMF)

Tags: xsd, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

What is the best way to convert `.xsd`-files into `.ecore`-files?

Is there an Eclipse plugin for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's what worked for me:

- New -> Project...
- Eclipse Modeling Framework -> EMF Project
- **Model Importers:** *XML Schema*
- **Model URIs**: *[Select xsd-File]*

To revalidate the .ecore-File when xsd has changed:

- Right-Click on *.genmodel*-File
- **Reload...**

Comment: In Galileo you have to install the feature "XSD Ecore Converter". This provides the model importer for XML Schema.

Comment: In never versions of Eclipse, this feature is contained in the "XSD - XML Schema Definition SDK" feature.

Comment: In the newer versions (neon 3 in my case), I needed to install [XML schema definition](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/downloads/?project=xsd). So I can see the XML schema importer.

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want to create a new MDT project every time you want to import a schema as ECore model then there is also another way to do this:

- New -> **EMF Generator Model** (in "Eclipse Modelling Framework")
- *Press Next*
- Select folder and **specify filename** (has to have the extension "genmodel")
- *Press Next*
- Select "**XML Schema**" as model importer
- *Press Next*
- Select URI to your **XSD**
- (Optionally, select tick box "Create XML Schema to Ecore Map" if you want to generate a .xsd2ecore map file)
- *Press Next*
- Select all desired **root packages**
- *Press **Finish***

Answer (score 4):

An example class. I did not clean up the imports.

```
 

import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.*;
import org.eclipse.xsd.*;
import org.eclipse.xsd.ecore.XSDEcoreBuilder;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.*;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceFactoryImpl;
import org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.*;


public class Xsd2Ecore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xsd2Ecore x2e = new Xsd2Ecore();
        x2e.go("UMLVersions/V1.0.0/UML2XMI.xsd", "UMLVersions/V1.0.0/UML2100.xmi");
    }


    public void go(String sourcename, String targetname) {

        System.out.println("Starting");

        XSDEcoreBuilder xsdEcoreBuilder = new XSDEcoreBuilder();
        ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
        Collection eCorePackages = xsdEcoreBuilder.generate(URI.createFileURI(sourcename));

        resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("xmi", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
        Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createFileURI(targetname));

        for (Iterator iter = eCorePackages.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            EPackage element = (EPackage) iter.next();
            resource.getContents().add(element);
        }

        try {
            resource.save(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Finished");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
eclipse –console –noExit –noSplash -data C:\temp\emf-ws
    -application org.eclipse.xsd.ecore.importer.XSD2GenModel
```

It generates .ecore and .genmodel for your set of XSDs.