# How to convert ecore (EMF) to xsd

Tags: eclipse, plugins, xsd, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

What is the best way to convert .ecore-files into .xsd-files?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671555/how-to-convert-xsd-to-ecore-emf

Comment: yes, but I need reverse convertion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have the feature **XSD Ecore Converter** installed (it's part of the [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project_summary.php?projectid=modeling.emf) project).

Then you can open the context menu on your ecore's generator model (extension `.genmodel`) and select *Export Model*. It should offer you now to export the ecore to XML schema.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, when only EMF SDK is installed, you may not be able to see the model exporter for "XML Schema". (On my side, only "UML model" is visible).

Use an update site with [EMF repository](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/releases/). Install the XSD features then the exporter would appear.