# Eclipse modeling tools for android java development

Tags: android, eclipse, uml, modeling, erd

I've been working in Eclipse Juno with ADT for a couple of years.  Eclipse has a "Modeling Tools" version that I've downloaded hoping to find UML and ERD modeling that can be used to diagrammatically design the data, logic and presentation layers for Android apps and then generate the prototypes and SQL code to create the template.  With the "Modeling Tools" version, you still need to install several components, many that I'm unfamiliar.
Is there a recommended or best-in-class configuration of tool components that would support this endeavor, minimize my learning curve and get me to a well functioning UML and ERD environment?

Comment: Here is the desired workflow; 1) visually design the app using class defs, inheritance, interfaces,...in a presentation, logic, data layer form, 2) create the code prototypes (codegen) from these diagrams (and underlying tables), 3) modify the gen'd prototype code as needed, 4) reverse these mods into the diags as needed, 5) create awesome documentation of the final app from the diagrams and associated design metadata, 6) have an ERD capability to model and generate the data store as either a database or structured file (e.g. XML, XSD..). These capabilities seem to be fragmented in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

you can read this tutorial for more detail about Eclipse modeling tools for android java development

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082765/converting-a-uml-class-diagram-created-using-papyrus-into-an-ecore-file - this is why I asked the original question.  with all of the editors, designers and generators being abandoned, does anyone have a 4Q2014 snapshot of the best modeling environment on Eclipse? I was hoping that by upgrading to Luna Modeling from Juno Modeling, that all of the necessary extensions would be bundled, however, this doesn't seem to be the case when it comes to code gen. @sarbjot link to the Vogella article from 12/2013 shows the  Generator Model wizard under EMF.